# Objective-C invalid operands to binary expression

Tags: objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

I am getting the error:

> invalid operands to binary expression ('UITextField')

my .h looks like this:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

    IBOutlet UILabel *resultLabel;
    float result;
    IBOutlet UITextField *miles;
    IBOutlet UITextField *mpgLoaded;
    IBOutlet UITextField *mpgEmpty;
    IBOutlet UITextField *fuelCost;
    IBOutlet UITextField *payment;
}

-(IBAction)result:(id)sender;

-(IBAction)reset:(id)sender;


@end
```

And the error is coming from the calculation I am trying to do in .m:

```
-(IBAction)result:(id)sender{
    result = payment - ((miles/mpgLoaded)*fuelCost)-((miles/mpgEmpty)*fuelCost);
    resultLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",result];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to ask each `UITextField` for its value (which is the `text` property), and convert each value from a string to a float.  E.g.

```
result = payment.text.floatValue - ((miles.text.floatValue / ...
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert your `UITextField` objects into numbers that you can do arithmetic with.

The `UITextField` class has the property "text" which contains an `NSString` representing the contents of the field.

So, for example:

```
NSString *milesString = miles.text;
```

To convert this into a float:

```
float milesValue = [milesString floatValue]
```

You can then do your arithmetic with `milesValue` and so on.

Of course you can simplify the assignment with:

```
float milesValue = [miles.text floatValue]
```